# sending an attachment output from sas using crontab

Tags: linux, email, cron

I am trying to send several attachments from Crontab after my SAS job completes.

My sas job output several .csv files and I'd like to attach them to the email crontab sends.

How do I this?

This code

```
echo "files attached" | mutt -a "file.csv" -s "week 1 day 1 files"
```

gives me this error:

```
/prod/file/sas-data2/monthly_goaling_process/macros/week1_day1_process: line 24: mutt: command not found CONFIDENTIALITY NOTICE:
```

Comment: As far as I understand this question doesn't have anything to do with SAS so I removed the tag.  You may want to include more of your script file as presumably something happens before this line.  But first, can you confirm that `mutt` is installed and in the `path`?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear :

```
 mutt: command not found
```

means that you have to install this app with your package manager, depends of your Linux flavor.

Another approach is to use `sendmail`command with `uuencode` (this later solution is more 'light')

Comment: Hi. I got this to work using uuencode. Now I'm struggling with trying to add in text into the body.

Comment: don't forget to upvote/accept answer if it fit your needs